# How to resolve list index out of range error?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, datetimepicker, plotly-dash

I have plotted sensor data onto a GEO map, below the map is the histogram, which shows the frequency of sensor-observations per hour. There are three drop-down entries to filter the data based on date-picker from a calendar, a sensor picker and an hour picker.

The sample code of Dash-Plotly takes initially its own example CSV file for the image above (location: NY). I took my own CSV and made sure to alter it according to the format of the example CSV's (location: Africa). Which resulted into the following data format (two row sample):

```
**Date/Time          Lat                 Lon**
2019-03-25 04:00:00 -10,80948998827914  24,19160777427344  
2019-03-25 04:05:00 -10,798684405083584 24,16288145431259
```

**My problem**: The calendar does not necessarily correlate to the actual available data in the CSV. When I select any date past (say) 7th of the month. It probably has to do with the totalList[] not shaping accordingly. Which means the problem might be at due to this snippet:

```
totalList = []
for month in df.groupby(df.index.month):
    dailyList = []
    for day in month[1].groupby(month[1].index.day):
        dailyList.append(day[1])
    totalList.append(dailyList)
totalList = np.array(totalList)
```

***As an example use-case***: in my CSV I have sensor observations for the date '2019-03-23'. So on the webpage when I select the date: March 23, 2019. I get the following errors:

```
- Callback error updating total-rides.children - IndexError: list index out of range

 File "/Frontend/app.py", line 262, in update_total_rides
    len(totalList[date_picked.month - 4][date_picked.day - 1])

- Callback error updating histogram.figure - IndexError: list index out of range

 File "/Frontend/app.py", line 322, in update_histogram
    [xVal, yVal, colorVal] = get_selection(monthPicked,dayPicked, selection) 

 File "/Users/Mieer/Desktop/DSP_Frontend/app.py", line 231, in **get_selection**
    yVal.append(len(totalList[month][day][totalList[month][day].index.hour== i]))

- Callback error updating map-graph.figure - IndexError: list index out of range

 File "/Frontend/app.py", line 419, in update_graph
    listCoords = getLatLonColor(selectedData, monthPicked,dayPicked) 

 File "/Users/Mieer/Desktop/DSP_Frontend/app.py", line 382, in **getLatLonColor**
    listCoords = totalList[month][day]
```

**

> **My Question**: How can one better correlate the actual CSV data with he calendar? So that I don't get range issue?

**

[image: Callback Graph]

**Below my code:**

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from datetime import datetime as dt


app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width"}]
)
server = app.server


# Plotly mapbox public token
mapbox_access_token = "pk.eyJ1IjoicGxvdGx5bWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNqdnBvNDMyaTAxYzkzeW5ubWdpZ2VjbmMifQ.TXcBE-xg9BFdV2ocecc_7g"

list_of_fixed_sensors = {
    "sensor_1_2": {"lat": -10.736196, "lon": 24.060188},
    "sensor_1_3": {"lat": -10.736196, "lon": 24.106700},
    "sensor_1_6": {"lat": -10.736196, "lon": 24.246292},

# Initialize data frame
df1 = pd.read_csv(
    "/Users/ME/Desktop/Frontend/sensor_points.csv",
    dtype=object,
)
df = pd.concat([df1], axis=0)
df["Date/Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
df.index = df["Date/Time"]
df.drop("Date/Time", 1, inplace=True)
totalList = []
for month in df.groupby(df.index.month):
    dailyList = []
    for day in month[1].groupby(month[1].index.day):
        dailyList.append(day[1])
    totalList.append(dailyList)
totalList = np.array(totalList)

# Layout of Dash App HTML 
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            className="row",
            children=[
                # Column for user controls
                html.Div(
                    className="four columns div-user-controls",
                    children=[
                        html.Img(
                            className="logo", src=app.get_asset_url("dash-logo-new-.png")
                        ),
                        html.H2("DASHBOARD - Park Monitoring"),
                        html.Div(
                            className="div-for-dropdown",
                            children=[
                                dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                                    id="date-picker",
                                    min_date_allowed=dt(2019, 3, 1),
                                    max_date_allowed=dt(2019, 12, 31),
                                    initial_visible_month=dt(2019, 3, 1),
                                    date=dt(2019, 3, 1).date(),
                                    display_format="MMMM DD, YYYY",
                                    style={"border": "0px solid white"}
                                )
                            ],
                        ),
                        # Change to side-by-side for mobile layout
                        html.Div(
                            className="row",
                            children=[
                                html.Div(
                                    className="div-for-dropdown",
                                    children=[
                                        # Dropdown for locations on map
                                        dcc.Dropdown(
                                            id="location-dropdown",
                                            options=[
                                                {"label": i, "value": i}
                                                for i in list_of_fixed_sensors
                                            ],
                                            placeholder="Select a location",
                                        )
                                    ],
                                ),
                                html.Div(
                                    className="div-for-dropdown",
                                    children=[
                                        # Dropdown to select times
                                        dcc.Dropdown(
                                            id="bar-selector",
                                            options=[
                                                {
                                                    "label": str(n) + ":00",
                                                    "value": str(n),
                                                }
                                                for n in range(24)
                                            ],
                                            multi=True,
                                            placeholder="Select certain hours",
                                        )
                                    ],
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        html.H1(id="total-rides"),
                        html.H1(id="total-rides-selection"),
                        html.H1(id="date-value"),
                    ],
                ),
                # Column for app graphs and plots
                html.Div(
                    className="eight columns div-for-charts bg-grey",
                    children=[
                        dcc.Graph(id="map-graph"),
                        html.Div(
                            className="text-padding",
                            children=[
                                "Select any of the bars on the histogram to section data by time."
                            ],
                        ),
                        dcc.Graph(id="histogram"),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]
)

# Gets the amount of days in the specified month
# Index represents month (0 is January, 1 is February, ... etc.)
daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

# Get index for the specified month in the dataframe
monthIndex = pd.Index(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])

# Get the amount of rides per hour based on the time selected
# This also higlights the color of the histogram bars based on
# if the hours are selected
def get_selection(month, day, selection):
    xVal = []
    yVal = []
    xSelected = []
    colorVal = [
        "#F4EC15",
        "#DAF017",
        "#BBEC19",
        "#9DE81B",
        "#80E41D",
        "#66E01F",
        "#4CDC20",
        "#34D822",
        "#24D249",
        "#25D042",
        "#26CC58",
        "#28C86D",
        "#29C481",
        "#2AC093",
        "#2BBCA4",
        "#2BB5B8",
        "#2C99B4",
        "#2D7EB0",
        "#2D65AC",
        "#2E4EA4",
        "#2E38A4",
        "#3B2FA0",
        "#4E2F9C",
        "#603099",
    ]

    # Put selected times into a list of numbers xSelected
    xSelected.extend([int(x) for x in selection])

    for i in range(24):
        # If bar is selected then color it white
        if i in xSelected and len(xSelected) < 24:
            colorVal[i] = "#FFFFFF"
        xVal.append(i)
        # Get the number of rides at a particular time
        yVal.append(len(totalList[month][day][totalList[month][day].index.hour == i]))
    return [np.array(xVal), np.array(yVal), np.array(colorVal)]


# Selected Data in the Histogram updates the Values in the DatePicker
@app.callback(
    Output("bar-selector", "value"),
    [Input("histogram", "selectedData"), Input("histogram", "clickData")],
)
def update_bar_selector(value, clickData):
    holder = []
    if clickData:
        holder.append(str(int(clickData["points"][0]["x"])))
    if value:
        for x in value["points"]:
            holder.append(str(int(x["x"])))
    return list(set(holder))


# Clear Selected Data if Click Data is used
@app.callback(Output("histogram", "selectedData"), [Input("histogram", "clickData")])
def update_selected_data(clickData):
    if clickData:
        return {"points": []}


# Update the total number of observations
@app.callback(Output("total-rides", "children"), [Input("date-picker", "date")])
def update_total_rides(datePicked):
    date_picked = dt.strptime(datePicked, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return "Total number of observations: {:,d}".format(
        len(totalList[date_picked.month - 4][date_picked.day - 1])
    )


# Update the total number of observations from selected bar in histogram
@app.callback(
    [Output("total-rides-selection", "children"), Output("date-value", "children")],
    [Input("date-picker", "date"), Input("bar-selector", "value")],
)
def update_total_rides_selection(datePicked, selection):
    firstOutput = ""

    if selection is not None or len(selection) is not 0:
        date_picked = dt.strptime(datePicked, "%Y-%m-%d")
        totalInSelection = 0
        for x in selection:
            totalInSelection += len(
                totalList[date_picked.month - 4][date_picked.day - 1][
                    totalList[date_picked.month - 4][date_picked.day - 1].index.hour
                    == int(x)
                ]
            )
        firstOutput = "Total observations for selected time: {:,d}".format(totalInSelection)

    if (
        datePicked is None
        or selection is None
        or len(selection) is 24
        or len(selection) is 0
    ):
        return firstOutput, (datePicked, " - showing hour(s): All")

    holder = sorted([int(x) for x in selection])

    if holder == list(range(min(holder), max(holder) + 1)):
        return (
            firstOutput,
            (
                datePicked,
                " - showing hour(s): ",
                holder[0],
                "-",
                holder[len(holder) - 1],
            ),
        )

    holder_to_string = ", ".join(str(x) for x in holder)
    return firstOutput, (datePicked, " - showing hour(s): ", holder_to_string)


# Update Histogram Figure based on Month, Day and Times Chosen
@app.callback(
    Output("histogram", "figure"),
    [Input("date-picker", "date"), Input("bar-selector", "value")],
)
def update_histogram(datePicked, selection):
    date_picked = dt.strptime(datePicked, "%Y-%m-%d")
    monthPicked = date_picked.month - 4
    dayPicked = date_picked.day - 1

    [xVal, yVal, colorVal] = get_selection(monthPicked, dayPicked, selection)

    layout = go.Layout(
        bargap=0.01,
        bargroupgap=0,
        barmode="group",
        margin=go.layout.Margin(l=10, r=0, t=0, b=50),
        showlegend=False,
        plot_bgcolor="#323130",
        paper_bgcolor="#323130",
        dragmode="select",
        font=dict(color="white"),
        xaxis=dict(
            range=[-0.5, 23.5],
            showgrid=False,
            nticks=25,
            fixedrange=True,
            ticksuffix=":00",
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            range=[0, max(yVal) + max(yVal) / 4],
            showticklabels=False,
            showgrid=False,
            fixedrange=True,
            rangemode="nonnegative",
            zeroline=False,
        ),
        annotations=[
            dict(
                x=xi,
                y=yi,
                text=str(yi),
                xanchor="center",
                yanchor="bottom",
                showarrow=False,
                font=dict(color="white"),
            )
            for xi, yi in zip(xVal, yVal)
        ],
    )

    return go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Bar(x=xVal, y=yVal, marker=dict(color=colorVal), hoverinfo="x"),
            go.Scatter(
                opacity=0,
                x=xVal,
                y=yVal / 2,
                hoverinfo="none",
                mode="markers",
                marker=dict(color="rgb(66, 134, 244, 0)", symbol="square", size=40),
                visible=True,
            ),
        ],
        layout=layout,
    )


# Get the Coordinates of the chosen months, dates and times
def getLatLonColor(selectedData, month, day):
    listCoords = totalList[month][day]

    # No times selected, output all times for chosen month and date
    if selectedData is None or len(selectedData) is 0:
        return listCoords
    listStr = "listCoords["
    for time in selectedData:
        if selectedData.index(time) is not len(selectedData) - 1:
            listStr += "(totalList[month][day].index.hour==" + str(int(time)) + ") | "
        else:
            listStr += "(totalList[month][day].index.hour==" + str(int(time)) + ")]"
    return eval(listStr)


# Update Map Graph based on date-picker, selected data on histogram and location dropdown
@app.callback(
    Output("map-graph", "figure"),
    [
        Input("date-picker", "date"),
        Input("bar-selector", "value"),
        Input("location-dropdown", "value"),
    ],
)
def update_graph(datePicked, selectedData, selectedLocation):
    zoom = 10.5
    latInitial = -10.736196
    lonInitial = 24.060188
    bearing = 0

    if selectedLocation:
        zoom = 13.0
        latInitial = list_of_fixed_sensors[selectedLocation]["lat"]
        lonInitial = list_of_fixed_sensors[selectedLocation]["lon"]

    date_picked = dt.strptime(datePicked, "%Y-%m-%d")
    monthPicked = date_picked.month - 4
    dayPicked = date_picked.day - 1
    listCoords = getLatLonColor(selectedData, monthPicked, dayPicked)

    return go.Figure(
        data=[
            # Data for all rides based on date and time
            Scattermapbox(
                lat=listCoords["Lat"],
                lon=listCoords["Lon"],
                mode="markers",
                hoverinfo="lat+lon+text",
                text=listCoords.index.hour,
                marker=dict(
                    showscale=True,
                    color=np.append(np.insert(listCoords.index.hour, 0, 0), 23),
                    opacity=0.5,
                    size=5,
                    colorscale=[
                        [0, "#F4EC15"],
                        [0.04167, "#DAF017"],
                        [0.0833, "#BBEC19"],
                        [0.125, "#9DE81B"],
                        [0.1667, "#80E41D"],
                        [0.2083, "#66E01F"],
                        [0.25, "#4CDC20"],
                        [0.292, "#34D822"],
                        [0.333, "#24D249"],
                        [0.375, "#25D042"],
                        [0.4167, "#26CC58"],
                        [0.4583, "#28C86D"],
                        [0.50, "#29C481"],
                        [0.54167, "#2AC093"],
                        [0.5833, "#2BBCA4"],
                        [1.0, "#613099"],
                    ],
                    colorbar=dict(
                        title="Time of<br>Day",
                        x=0.93,
                        xpad=0,
                        nticks=24,
                        tickfont=dict(color="#d8d8d8"),
                        titlefont=dict(color="#d8d8d8"),
                        thicknessmode="pixels",
                    ),
                ),
            ),
             # Plot of fixed sensors on the map
            Scattermapbox(
                lat=[list_of_fixed_sensors[i]["lat"] for i in list_of_fixed_sensors],
                lon=[list_of_fixed_sensors[i]["lon"] for i in list_of_fixed_sensors],
                mode="markers",
                marker=dict(size=8,  color='white', symbol='square', opacity=0.2),
                hoverinfo="text",
                text=[i for i in list_of_fixed_sensors],
            ),
        ],
        layout=Layout(
            autosize=True,
            margin=go.layout.Margin(l=0, r=35, t=0, b=0),
            showlegend=False,
            mapbox=dict(
                accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                center=dict(lat=latInitial, lon=lonInitial),
                style="dark",
                bearing=bearing,
                zoom=zoom,
            ),
            updatemenus=[
                dict(
                    buttons=(
                        [
                            dict(
                                args=[
                                    {
                                        "mapbox.zoom": 10.5,
                                        "mapbox.center.lon": "24.060188",
                                        "mapbox.center.lat": "-10.736196",
                                        "mapbox.bearing": 0,
                                        "mapbox.style": "dark",
                                    }
                                ],
                                label="Reset Zoom",
                                method="relayout",
                            )
                        ]
                    ),
                    direction="left",
                    pad={"r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0, "l": 0},
                    showactive=False,
                    type="buttons",
                    x=0.45,
                    y=0.02,
                    xanchor="left",
                    yanchor="bottom",
                    bgcolor="#323130",
                    borderwidth=1,
                    bordercolor="#6d6d6d",
                    font=dict(color="#FFFFFF"),
                )
            ],
        ),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```